# Getting price to display if New, or Reconditioned

Tags: magento-1.9, price, out-of-stock, stock-status, new-products

[image]So I am trying to create a function that states that if the product is new in stock then display price, or if the product is not new but reconditioned then I want it to display the reconditioned price, and lastly if there is none of the product in stock to display a "call for pricing" message. I am looking to do this in the price.phtml file and would like to know how to do this, I have an idea of what I want to do but I'm not entirely sure how to execute this code, please help! The image added is essentially what I would like to be done with code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rewriting the `price.phtml` I would use the `catalog_product_get_final_price` event that is triggered from `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price::getFinalPrice`

In your observeryou can set the final_price data of a product

```
$observer->getProduct()->setData('final_price', $ yourCustomPrice);
```

This will overwrite other previously set prices

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand, so if not in price.phtml, then where?

Comment: As I mentioned I would use an observer. you can add one by creating your own module and defining the observer

Comment: I'm not sure, I have created a module for custom php before, but this should be simpler, could it not? I'm not intending to write up an entire new price.phtml file but more so adding a few lines of code to it. I believe I have price information for New and Reconditioned products in Magento so I was hoping to just call to that with a function for the products in the Price.phtml file.

Comment: @Mhernandez I've done this several times before and found it to be the easiest and cleanest way to do this. Works consistently and is easily scalable

Comment: ok, so looking at the image I've now added, could I do that for what is detailed in the image? also you said I would do this by creating a module, so just to be perfectly clear the code you gave me would go where? In a custom php file after I've created all module.xml file as well as the config file? or would it go somewhere else?

Comment: The first one, yes, the second one is tricky since it's not price but more of a text label. Would mean buy buttons should be disabled as well. In short that one should return from `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::isSaleable` *false*

Comment: Ok, so this would need to all be put in the same php file? and where would that php file? I'm going to try what you said, but now I'm just trying to see where the file would go, so how would I need to make this file, with all the xml files and then put the php code in the correct directory?

Comment: Also I'm not sure how the code you gave, satisfies my need for the first one, could you explain in more detail how the code you gave achieves the function that if the product is new in stock then to display the New price, the Reconditioned price, and the Repair:Call for estimate message?

Comment: Can you help me understand a little bit more as to what exactly I should do here? I believe I can do what you said I just need more clarification.

Comment: Hello @Sander Mangel could you explain to me how I should do this in more detail? Like where to put the $observer code and how to make it more specific to the situation.

Comment: you can find more on observers here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/custom-events-in-magento-with-the-observer-pattern--cms-22120 

I'm sorry but I'm afraid I don't have a lot of time to work it out more. If you're unsure on how to do it It's probably better to either ask a more experienced coworker or go for asimpler solution

Comment: Thank you for what you have given me, I know you said you have no more time to contribute to this but could you possibly give me an idea of a simpler solution?